# how to merge multiple row in one single row

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, stored-functions, listagg

how can i reach the expected output?i cannot type much i dont know i keep getting format issues.Thanks in advance. i know my cursor is wrong as it is looping n number of times for each nation belonging to that particular region. But i do not know how i can go about it hope someone can enlighten me.

**Script:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION listnation(regionN CHAR) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  nationlist VARCHAR2(400);
BEGIN
  SELECT r_regionkey || ' ' || TRIM(r_name) || ':'
    INTO nationlist
    FROM region, nation
   WHERE r_name = regionN
     AND r_regionkey = n_regionkey
     AND rownum = 1;
  FOR i IN 
  (
   SELECT n_name
     FROM nation, region
    WHERE r_name = regionN
      AND r_regionkey = n_regionkey
  )
  LOOP 
    nationlist := nationlist || TRIM(i.n_name)||',';
  END LOOP; 
  RETURN nationlist;
END listnation;
/
```

**Expected output:**

```
0 AFRICA:ALGERIA,ETHIOPIA,KENYA,MOROCCO,MOZAMBIQUE
```

**Current:**

```
SQL> SELECT listnation('AFRICA') FROM region;

LISTNATION('AFRICA')
---------------------------------------------------
0 AFRICA:ALGERIA,MOROCCO,MOZAMBIQUE,ETHIOPIA,KENYA
0 AFRICA:ALGERIA,MOROCCO,MOZAMBIQUE,ETHIOPIA,KENYA
0 AFRICA:ALGERIA,MOROCCO,MOZAMBIQUE,ETHIOPIA,KENYA
0 AFRICA:ALGERIA,MOROCCO,MOZAMBIQUE,ETHIOPIA,KENYA
0 AFRICA:ALGERIA,MOROCCO,MOZAMBIQUE,ETHIOPIA,KENYA
```

**Conceptual schema:**

[image: conceptual schema]

**Criteria of this qns:**

Need to implement a stored PL/SQL function `LISTNATION` that finds the names of the nations of an individual region specified by a region name. The function must return a string of characters that contains the region key, region name and all nation names, which are seperated by commas, in the desired format that's already explained above.

Comment: show us the SQL that you have tried?

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Read this too - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please convert those images to text and format as code. If you don't know how to format then just post text and we'll format for you.

Comment: You probably don't need a loop at all. Post your SQL as text.

Comment: Hint : `LISTAGG()` function

Comment: create or replace function LISTNATION(regionN char)
return varchar2 IS
nationlist varchar2(400);
begin

 
Select r_regionkey||' '||trim(r_name)||':'
into nationlist from region,nation 
where r_name = regionN and r_regionkey = n_regionkey and rownum=1;

for i in 
(select n_name from nation,region where r_name=regionN and 
r_regionkey = n_regionkey)
loop
nationlist := nationlist||trim(i.n_name)||',';
end loop;

return nationlist;
end listnation;
/

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan i tried that, not working for me. and it has to be in a function.

Comment: @MichaelZ. mmm... just posted as text , not sure if that's doable

Comment: @LimWenTeck I have no way of testing this SQL engine, but it looks like Barbaros Özhan's hint of `LISTAGG()` is probably the solution.

Comment: But how can I use listagg  inside a function?

Comment: @LimWenTeck Why do you need this as a function? If it's a learning exercise, then fair enough, but in a production environment, I'd most likely create a view with the suggested `LISTAGG()` solution.

Comment: @boneist yes, it’s as a learning exercise

Answer (score 1):

Using a [`LISTAGG()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html#GUID-B6E50D8E-F467-425B-9436-F7F8BF38D466) function would be enough to get the desired string such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION listnation(regionN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  nationlist VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
   SELECT r_regionkey || ' ' || TRIM(r_name) || ':'||
          LISTAGG( n_name, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY n_name)
     INTO nationlist     
     FROM nation
     JOIN region
       ON r_regionkey = n_regionkey
    WHERE UPPER(r_name) = UPPER(regionN)
    GROUP BY r_regionkey, r_name;
   
  RETURN nationlist;
 EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN RETURN NULL;
END;
/
```

where

- neither double SQL SELECT Statement or a LOOP is needed
- do not prefer using old-fashioned comma-seperated join style for the tables within the SQL SELECT Statement
- `UPPER()` or `LOWER()` conversion would be suitable against
  case-sensitivity problems
- the length of the local variable `nationlist` might be prolonged
  against the probability of non-fitting result string
- removing the trailing comma won't be needed to be handled through use of this function unlike to the current case
- seems an ordering criteria, which is handled through use of `ORDER BY n_name` clause along with the function , would be needed for the
  country names

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=372fe03e949730314670942a9a1c9e27)</kbd>

Comment: thanks ! but strangely it returns no value on the virtual machine. Unless i am doing in wrong by using
select listnation('africa') from region;

Comment: you're welcome @LimWenTeck , make sure that you reproduced the demo in your DB. Btw, `n_regionkey` column is missing within the `nation` table in your conceptual schema.

Comment: sorry , but i not sure what the above is  and i tried to run 
SELECT * FROM nls_instance_parameters

i dont see any return keyword from the output

Comment: PARAMETER
---------------------------
VALUE
--------------
NLS_LANGUAGE
AMERICAN

NLS_TERRITORY
AMERICA

NLS_SORT


NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE


NLS_DATE_FORMAT


NLS_CURRENCY


NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS


NLS_ISO_CURRENCY


NLS_CALENDAR


NLS_TIME_FORMAT


NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT


NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT


NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT


NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY

NLS_COMP
BINARY

NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS
BYTE

NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP
FALSE

Comment: excuse me @LimWenTeck that was a typo. The correct one is `SELECT value FROM nls_instance_parameters WHERE parameter = 'NLS_LANGUAGE'`. OK, I see that value of your NLS_LANGUAGE is AMERICAN, then no problem should occur stems from the string `africa` ....

Comment: mm... no idea why, this is weird